# Stream groupingBy with flatmap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<ServiceName> servicesNames` and ServiceName has this structure:

```
public class ServiceName {
private Map<String, String> names;
}
```

Where `names` is a Hashmap with language and name - usually several values.

I'm trying to get `Map<String lang, List<String> names>>` - where key is language and value is a List of all the names in given language from `List<ServiceName>`.

Here is what I came by so far but can;t just put  it together - getting compilation errors:

```java
servicesNames
    .stream()
    .map(x -> x.getNames())
    .flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(x -> Collectors.groupingBy());
```

EDIT:
I'm able to get this:

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> collect1 = servicesNames
    .stream()
    .map(x -> x.getNames())
    .flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But don't know to to actually group by key all the values after using flatmap...

Comment: It would help a bit if you actually posted your compilation error.. You need `groupingBy(Entry::getKey)` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: added edit with what I got so far - compilation error is actually meaningless, lots of generics and stuff

Comment: Please include it. Otherwise it is hard to tell where exactly in your method chain the error pops up. If it's too hard to understand then please create a proper [mcve] with different code that demonstrates the issue better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) to group the values by a key and apply mapping to the downstream by [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

The lambda-based approach:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = servicesNames
        .stream()
        .flatMap(service -> service.getNames().entrySet().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), mapping(e -> e.getValue(), toList())));
```

The method reference-based approach:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = servicesNames
        .stream()
        .map(ServiceName::getNames)
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

Comment: May I suggest showing two versions, one only using method references and one only using lambdas, instead of writing it partially in text? The lambda-only version would combine the `map` and `flatmap` into a single `flatmap`, while the method-reference-only version would split `flatmap` into a `map` and a `flatmap`.